# Error when adding a List to custom adapter - Android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have a class that takes 4 parameters for a List. The class is called Item. I created a List  variables that is an ArrayList . I then create a new ListAdapter. I set this adapter to the main ListView. I then add 10 inputs into the the ArrayList. This all works but when I try to add the ArrayList Items to the ListAdapter is gives me an error saying to add a Cast to the method.

Here is the code that I am talking about

```
 final List <Item> tempList = new ArrayList <Item>();

     mainListViewListAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.main_list_item_layout, tempList);
      // set mainListAdapter
      mainListView.setAdapter(mainListViewListAdapter);

      for (int x = 0; x < 10;x++){
          tempList.add (new Item ("Example1","Example2","Example3","Example4"));
        }

       ***HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR AT addAll();***
      mainListViewListAdapter.addAll(tempList);
```

mainListViewListAdapter is set to ListAdapter, and mainListView is set to ListView.

Why would I add a cast to mainListViewListAdapter? I have run this code on another project and I didn't have to use a cast.

Comment: To avoid this error you can add items before setting adapter.  And remove line with addAll method, if it's not important to use it exactly this way.

Comment: Good idea but I need to add them after setting the adapter because items are added to the listadapter multiple times during the activity

Comment: I figured out the answer. `ListAdapter` needed to be in front of `mainListViewListAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.main_list_item_layout, tempList);`

Answer (score 0):

Need destroy adapter - after using and configure each time use - new StringArray of Values for Adapter and new Adapter.

Use about this constructionale:

```
    String[] values1 = new String[] { "Sunny", "Sealand", "Lengord" };

    makeListItem(values1);

    public void makeListItem(String[] addValues){

MySimpleArrayAdapter lvAdapter1 = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, addValues);

ListView1.setAdapter(lvAdapter1);   lvAdapter1 = null;  }
```